# cross-domain ajax - works for me

Tags: ajax, jquery, cross-domain

http://jsbin.com/eyikac/3/edit#javascript,html,live - this works for me.  I thought I wasn't allowed to do cross-domain calls with ajax?

Question being this - what is the issue w/ cross-domain ajax calls, and, is there still an issue?  So far I've been able to do this, and I'm confused.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working because the domain explicitly allows jsbin to make crossdomain requests:

```
Request URL:http://opensocial.flixster.com/igoogle/showtimes?date=20111027&postal=23226
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
    Response Headers
        Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
        Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://jsbin.com
```

It is documented here https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control

Comment: further question, this page, http://bakersdozen13.lfchosting.com/movies/test.html

works on firefox, chrome, but not IE.  does IE just not support cross-domain ajax'ing at all?

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://bakersdozen13.lfchosting.com`. It appears they are changing it dynamically to allow any page.

Yes IE does not support the header

Answer (score 0):

you can load remote page code put you can't post data and get response

Comment: but, if you try and get from a site like www.cnn.com, it does not work. example: http://jsbin.com/ogused/edit#javascript,html,live